# Add custom columns on many to many relationship on NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have a movie entity and a actor entity, these 2 entities have a many to many relationship, so I've mapped it as `ManyToMany(x=>x.Movies)` and `ManyToMany(x=>x.Actors)` but i'd like to have the character the actor played on the movie, it should stay on the `MoviesActorsPivot` as a new column

But how can I do that using the Fluent Nhibernate Mapping in a way that I could get and save the data as easy as nhibernate does?

Not creating the pivot table manually and making the `HasMany(x => x.MoviesActorsPivot)` on both sides and managing the association by my own.

**Edit:**

Or if I map it creating the `HasMany(x => x.MoviesActorsPivot)` on both sides, how would i manage to insert and get al data like all movies from an actor or all actors that act on a movie, getting all the characters names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

> NHibernate native **`many-to-many`** mapping does not support any additional setting on the pairing table

But, it could be replaced with a pairing object being first level citizen

```
public class MovieActor 
{
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor Actor { get; set; }
    ... // more properties here
    public virtual int Rating { get; set; }
}

public class Actor
{
    public virtual IList<MovieActor> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie 
{
    public virtual IList<MovieActor> Actors { get; set; }    
}
```

That would be standard `HasMany` and `References` mapping. And the queriyng later will be more easier

Also check these:

- [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15510748/1679310)
- [nhibernate many to many with multiple table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29158253/1679310)
- [many-to-many with extra columns nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22563082/1679310)