# Hibernate many to many with extra column in join table

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I'm searching for hibernate many to many sample with extra columns in join table (XML mapping). I searched a lot and could not find. Could you please provide me a working example. Thank you very much.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16827671/1679310) with some explanation how to. It could give you some hints

Comment: @Sujith Maliyadda check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) out.

Comment: @ankur-singhal Thank you. But, it is for annotation mapping. I'm looking for XML mapping.

Comment: Hi did you figure this out, I need to do the same thing but all the tutorials show annotation based solutions