# Nhibernate nested-composite-element containing collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an enity 'Foo' which contains a collection of value objects 'Person', person consist of simple properties like "name" and a a collection of value objects 'NameChange', which is information about previous person names.

I wanted to map it as:

```
<class name="Foo">
  <bag name="Persons">
    <composite-element class="Person">
      <property name="Name"/>
      <bag name="NameChanges"> <!--WRONG-->
        <composite-element class="NameChange">
          <property name="ExName"/>
        </composite-element>
      </bag>
    </composite-element>
  </bag>
</class>
```

But NH doesnt allow such mapping.

How to map collection of value objects inside value object?

Comment: You need to define person as a new class mapping and put the name changes collection there.

Comment: @MarkPM But, my Person is value object it doesn't have ID

Comment: So how do you retrieve it from the DB? By name?

Comment: @MarkPM I, do not retrieve Person objects from DB, they are value objects, I retrieve 'Foo' Entity by its PK, child value objects collection is retreived by NH using FK defined inside <bag> <key column="FK"/>

Answer (score 1):

Check the doc:

#### [7.2. Collections of dependent objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-incollections)

> Collections of components are supported (eg. an array of type Name). Declare your component collection by replacing the  tag with a  tag.

```
<set name="SomeNames" table="some_names" lazy="true">
    <key column="id"/>
    <composite-element class="Eg.Name, Eg"> <!-- class attribute required -->
        <property name="Initial"/>
        <property name="First"/>
        <property name="Last"/>
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

> *Note: if you define an ISet of composite elements, it is very important to implement Equals() and GetHashCode() correctly.*
>
> Composite elements may contain components **but not collections.** If your composite element itself contains components, use the **`<nested-composite-element>`** tag. **This is a pretty exotic case - a collection of components which themselves have components. By this stage you should be asking yourself if a one-to-many** association is more appropriate.....

So to answer your question:

> How to map collection of value objects inside value object?

Do not do that. Create first level citizens entities, and map them with `one-to-many`. You gain a lot later, once you will be asked to provide filtering...

*Maybe check similar stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16827671/1679310)... My advice/suggestion would be: use mostly `one-to-many` and `many-to-one`... I do that 99,7% cases*

Comment: I see, _Composite elements may contain components but not collections._

Comment: Yes exactly. But really, if you plan to have succesful application.. you will soon need searching. I strongly suggest, use standard entities with many to one and one to many. That makes handling and searching easy... trust me ;) Good luck with NHibernate anyhow ;)